# SQLITE LIKE Поиск по нескольким доп параметрам

Tags: android, sqlite, like

Есть таблица такого плана:

[image: Тэйбал]

При поиске к примеру индекса 32, нужно возвращать так же `32А` и `32Б` если таковые имеются.

Не могу разобраться как составить запрос.

Т.е Строгое соответствие + буква А и Б, если присутствует.
Индексы могут быть только `А` или `Б`. Других нет.

Формирую запрос таким образом

```
public Cursor findStation(String my_id) {
    String TABLE_NAME = "station_list_mod";
    String COLUMN = "station_id";
    myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
    return myDataBase.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                    + " WHERE " + COLUMN
                    + " LIKE  '" + my_id+ "'",
            null);
}
```

Comment: Для ЛЮБОЙ, но одной, буквы, достаточно `WHERE column = 11 OR column LIKE '11_'` либо, скажем, `WHERE LEFT(column,2) = 11 AND LENGTH(column) < 4`... в общем, вариантов масса. Для строго ничего, А или Б - лучше использовать `WHERE column IN ('11','11A','11Б')`

Comment: Мне  нужно возвращать  мой запрос - my_id и при этом проверять есть ли  my_id + А, my_id + Б. Не совсем дорубаю как привильно составить запрос. Щас поэксперементирую, спасибо

Comment: *Мне нужно возвращать мой запрос - my_id и при этом проверять есть ли my_id + А, my_id + Б.* Это противоречит тому, что написано в вопросе. Попробуйте получше продумать формулировку.

Comment: Как бы это правильно сформулировать. Я делаю выборку индекса из списка. там такой порядок - 1, 2 , 3 , 3А, 4.......55, 55А,55Б, 56.... и так далее. То есть в некоторых случаях может быть с индексами а и б. Вот как запросить что бы находило и их тоже. Если ставлю процент, возвращается не совсем так как задумано мной))))

Comment: Сформулируйте чётко, например, типа "исходные данные '11', надо вернуть '11', a также '11А' и '11Б', если они присутствуют, но если '11' отсутствует, ничего не возвращать, даже если присутствуют '11А' и/или '11Б'". Что дано, что нужно получить в итоге, рассмотрев ВСЕ возможные варианты. Также уточните, возможно ли, например, присутствие '11АБ'...

Comment: Я поправил вопрос

Comment: С учётом поправок условие типа `WHERE station_id IN ('11','11A','11Б')` является наиболее эффективным и простым решением.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо.  Добавьте в ответы , я отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учётом поправок, внесённых в исходный вопрос, условие типа

```
WHERE station_id IN ('11','11A','11Б')
```

является наиболее эффективным и простым решением.

Answer (score 1):

- `%` в выражении LIKE сравнивает любое количество (от 0 - их может и не быть) любых символов
- `_` обязательно должен присутствовать любой символ

  ```
  "LIKE  '" + my_id+ "%'"
  ```